# Running out of RAM while doing pip install on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pytorch

I created EC2 instance (t2.micro, 1 GiB of RAM, 30 GiB of Disk).
I connected to the instance then successfully installed flask as

```
pip3 install flask
```

But when I try to install PyTorch as

```
pip3 install torch
```

it fails on the last moment:

```
Collecting torch
  Downloading torch-2.2.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (755.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸ 754.9/755.5 MB 32.8 MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running out of RAM memory. You can check it in another terminal by running `watch free -h`, while running `pip install torch` in another terminal.

To fix it, I would recommend you create a swap file. Swap files act as additional RAM memory, but it's a bit slow as it runs from the hard drive. However they are useful when you want to allocate a memory peak, as it is your case. The following example shows how to create a 5GB swap file:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G ~/swapfile
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=~/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576
sudo chmod 600 ~/swapfile
sudo mkswap ~/swapfile
sudo swapon ~/swapfile
```

Keep in mind that t2.micro instances are very limited. Be mindful of what you do and consider upgrading to a larger instance if needed.